# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when i try to start up my server

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, server, jboss, pom.xml

I am trying to start up my jboss server to run a web app that uses hibernate to connect it with my SqlServer DB.

When i try to start the server, the log console shows the following trace:

```
08:19:28,503 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/vp301b]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in VFS resource ["/C:/jbossNuevo3/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/deployments/vp301b-ear.ear/vp301b.war/WEB-INF/classes/spring/database.xml"]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/util/ClassLoaderHelper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) [spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) [spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3780) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/util/ClassLoaderHelper
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<init>(Ejb3Configuration.java:175) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.21.Final.jar:4.2.21.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.java:44) [spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) [spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384) [spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) [spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) [spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1688) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1626) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.internal.util.ClassLoaderHelper from [Module "deployment.vp301b-ear.ear.vp301b.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 31 more
```

I think that the problem is surely in the  pom.xml file,I had to add some hibernate dependencies.

hibernate dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.15.0-GA</version>
 </dependency>

<!-- Debe ser la última dependencia en definir -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am using Java 7 in the JRE and JDK, can it be a version conflict?

Comment: can try mvn clean and install before running on server

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate/JPA is already provided by your JBoss server. You either should mark them as provided in your pom or exclude the modules with a jboss-deployment-structure.xml